# SAS Datetime25.6 to Character YYYYMMDD

Tags: sas

Original Value is in DATETIME25.6

I need to change it to YYYYMMDD

I am using the below in a datastep;

```
'Date of Birth'n = put(borrower_dob,yymmddn8.);
```

However it returns ******** as the value. Help!

Comment: Unless your datetime value is before 6AM on 01JAN1960 it is going to be much too large a number to be displayed AS IF it was a date value.  You need to first convert it to a date value, or use a datetime format instead of a date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just the date part(days) of the date time(seconds)variable.  Check the documentation for explanation of SAS date and date-time variables.

'Date of Birth'n = put(**DATEPART**(borrower_dob),yymmddn8.);

Comment: Ahh, I missed the damn DATEPART. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

The date part of a SAS datetime value can be output with the format `B8601DN8.`

From docs

> B8601DNw.Format
>   Writes dates from datetime values by using the ISO8601 basic notation yyyymmdd.

```
data want;    
  dtnow = datetime();
  format dtnow datetime20.;

  put dtnow= B8601dn8. 'is the yyyymmdd rendering of ' dtnow=;

  yyyymmddstring = put (dtnow, B8601DN8.);
run;

----- LOG -----
dtnow=20191003 is the yyyymmdd rendering of dtnow=03OCT2019:10:02:14
```